# How to measure Json array length according to key value using Angular.js or Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need help.I need to measure json array length based on key value using Angular.js or Javascript.I am explaining my code below.

```
[{"day_id":"1","b":"sss"},
  {"day_id":"2","b":"ffff"},
  {"day_id":"3","b":"ccc"},
  {"day_id":"3","b":"hhh"},
{"day_id":"4","b":"kkk"}]
```

Here i need to measure the length where `day_id=3 or 2 etc` eans how many set of data present where `day_id=3` and here for 3 there are 2 set of data present.Please help me.

Comment: Have to try to write a function to loop and get the data ? I think its not possible in js.

Comment: Look for angular.forEach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var testArr = [{"day_id":"1","b":"sss"},
  {"day_id":"2","b":"ffff"},
  {"day_id":"3","b":"ccc"},
  {"day_id":"3","b":"hhh"},
{"day_id":"4","b":"kkk"}];

function getCount(arr,key,value){
  var count = 0;
  arr.forEach(function(obj){
    if(obj[key] == value){
      count++;
    }
  });
  return count;
}

console.log(getCount(testArr,'day_id','3'));
//2
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/tadikupapu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

This can help you.

```
function filterData(data, key, val){
   var result = [];
   for(var i=0;i< data.length; i++){
      if ((data[i][key]) && (data[i][key] == val)) {
         result.push(data[i]);
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

You can use it as `filterData(data, "day_id", 3)`

Disclaimer: It can have typos.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is using angular.

```js
// data is your array
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "day_id": "1",
    "b": "sss"
  }, {
    "day_id": "2",
    "b": "ffff"
  }, {
    "day_id": "3",
    "b": "ccc"
  }, {
    "day_id": "3",
    "b": "hhh"
  }, {
    "day_id": "4",
    "b": "kkk"
  }];
  $scope.count = $filter('filter')($scope.data, {
    day_id: 1
  }).length;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Count: {{count}}
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a more generic solution, it takes an object with the property to search for and the value.

It iterates over the array and count if the wanted property hast the same value.

```js
function getCount(array, search) {
    var c = 0,
        k = Object.keys(search)[0];

    array.forEach(function (a) {
        a[k] === search[k] && c++;
    });
    return c;
}

var array = [{ "day_id": "1", "b": "sss" }, { "day_id": "2", "b": "ffff" }, { "day_id": "3", "b": "ccc" }, { "day_id": "3", "b": "hhh" }, { "day_id": "4", "b": "kkk" }];
document.write(getCount(array, { day_id: '2' }) + '<br>');
document.write(getCount(array, { day_id: '3' }) + '<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Array.prototype.filter** method:

```
var filtered_array = your_array.filter(function(row) {
    return row.day_id = "3"
});

var day_id_count = filtered_array.length
```

Comment: Or, if the filtered array is not required for other purposes  : `your_array.filter (function (row) {  return row.day_id = "3" }).length`

Answer (score 0):

try this.you can use filter function on arrays

```js
var arr = [{
  "day_id": "1",
  "b": "sss"
}, {
  "day_id": "2",
  "b": "ffff"
}, {
  "day_id": "3",
  "b": "ccc"
}, {
  "day_id": "3",
  "b": "hhh"
}, {
  "day_id": "4",
  "b": "kkk"
}]

Array.prototype.findCountByPropertyValue=function(property_name,value)
{
  return arr.filter(function(i) { return i[property_name] == value}).length
}
document.write(arr.findCountByPropertyValue('day_id',1))
document.write('<br>')
document.write(arr.findCountByPropertyValue('day_id',2))
document.write('<br>')
document.write(arr.findCountByPropertyValue('day_id',3))
document.write('<br>')
document.write(arr.findCountByPropertyValue('day_id',4))
document.write('<br>')
document.write(arr.findCountByPropertyValue('day_id',5))
```